# I want an alert box to be displayed and after that my input field to stay on focus when it's value is empty

Tags: jquery, focus, formvalidation-plugin

I am doing modal form validation and on button click, i want an alert message to be displayed and my unfilled input field to stay on focus until it is filled. But that doesn't work.  I created a function: submitForm() but when i click the submit button it displays an alert message and refreshes the page but doesn't focus on the input field

Here is my  submitForm function:

```
function submitForm(){
 var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var name = $('#Input1_username').val();
    var email = $('#Input2_email').val();
    var password = $('#Input3_password').val();
    var confirmPassword = $('#Input4_Cpassword').val();
    if(name.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your name.');
        $('#Input1_username').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your email.');
        $('#Input2_email').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)){
        alert('Please enter valid email.');
        $('#Input2_email').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(password.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your password.');
        $('#Input3_password').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(confirmPassword.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please confirm your password.');
        $('#Input4_Cpassword').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(confirmPassword != password){
        alert('Please confirm your password 2.');
        $('#Input4_Cpassword').focus();
        return false;
    }
    
    else{ alert ("Try Again");}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8664486/328193)

Comment: Sorry i don't want to return to the previous page instead i want to focus on the input fields since they are empty.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking then... Currently the described behavior is that the page is refreshed (implying that a form was submitted), is that the correct expected behavior or not?  If you want focus to return to a field on the current page then clearly you don't want the page to refresh, correct?

Comment: on submission i want the inputs to be verified first then if a certain condition is met it can display a alert box , refresh the page and store the inputs in the my database or else it focuses on the input that doesn't meet the specified condition and stays in the modal window without refreshing the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem immediately, change your inline code from
`<form onsubmit="submitForm()"` or `<button onclick="submitForm()"` to `<form onsubmit="return submitForm()"`

However I strongly advice you

Add `required` and delete all the parts that refer to empty field, leaving only the email and the confirm password tests

Alternatively only alert once and focus only once

In any case use preventDefault to stop the submission - the reason your script does not focus is because the page is reloaded because you did not stop the form from submitting

```js
$("#formId").on("submit", (e) => {
  var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  const name = $('#Input1_username').val();
  const email = $('#Input2_email').val();
  const password = $('#Input3_password').val();
  const confirmPassword = $('#Input4_Cpassword').val();
  const errors = [];
  let focusId;
  if (name.trim() == '') {
    focusId = 'Input1_username';
    errors.push('Please enter your name.');
  } else if (email.trim() == '') {
    if (errors.length === 0) focusId = 'Input2_email';
    console.log(focusId);
    errors.push('Please enter your email.');
  } else if (!reg.test(email)) {
    if (errors.length === 0) focusId = 'Input2_email';
    console.log(focusId);
    errors.push('Please enter valid email.');
  } else if (password.trim() == '') {
    if (errors.length === 0) focusId = 'Input3_password';
    errors.push('Please enter your password.');
  } else if (confirmPassword.trim() == '') {
    if (errors.length === 0) focusId = 'Input4_Cpassword';
    errors.push('Please confirm your password.');
  } else if (confirmPassword != password) {
    if (errors.length === 0) focusId = 'Input4_Cpassword';
    errors.push('Please confirm your password 2.');
  }
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    alert(errors.join('\n'));
    console.log(focusId);
    $(`#${focusId}`).focus();
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formId">
  <label><input type="text" id="Input1_username" name="Input1_username" /> User name</label><br/>
  <label><input type="text" id="Input2_email" name="Input2_email" /> Email</label><br/>
  <label><input type="password" id="Input3_password" name="Input3_password" /> Password</label><br/>
  <label><input type="password" id="Input4_Cpassword" name="Input4_Cpassword" /> Check password</label><br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed my inline code from <button onclick="submitForm()" to <form onsubmit="return submitForm()" and got the exact result i wanted.

Comment: Have a look at my example